# Как правильно указать обязательные параметры запроса?

Tags: php, symfony

Допустим я хочу чтобы запрос выглядел так: `/models?prop=123` и при этом параметр `prop` был обязательным. Как мне это сделать? Я видел пример где параметр указывается просто параметром метода контроллера `public function modelsAction(Request $request, int $prop)`, но там в аннотации задается путь явный типа: `/models/<prop>`, а не так как мне надо. Можно конечно получить этот параметр через `$request->query->get('param')`, но как быть с обязательностью? Разве что вручную кинуть исключение если параметр пуст?

Comment: Вручную проверять. Или сделать `/models/123` и получать как параметры маршрута. Тогда в аннотации можно будет проверки поставить

Comment: @DmitryKozlov ок, раз по другому никак

Comment: можно пойти по сложному пути, прописать евенты на запрос, проверяющие наличие перед передачей в контроллер. но это имхо большой геморрой

Comment: _там в аннотации задается путь явный типа: /models/<prop>, а мне так как мне надо_ 

Объясните, почему вам так не надо, если вы говорите про обязательность какого либо значения?

По остальному - параметр, указанный в сигнатуре контроллера это не причина, а следствие. Т.е. на самом деле параметр указан в аннотациях, а уж если вы хотите его получить как свойство в функции, то указываете в сигнатуре, тем самым за вас работает  paramconverter - мега фича, как по мне, однако нарушает принцип единой ответственности.